# How to sort multiple columns in one dropdown list?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet of best mobile phones. They have different ranking such as Overall Rank, Camera Rank, Performance Ranks in different columns. What I wish to do is to have a single column with a dropdown list containing these options(Overall rank, camera rank etc) and sort the data depending on which one I choose

Comment: I believe that pivot tables can do this without too much difficulty.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am a very beginner to excel. I'm just trying out random methods

Comment: Sorting in Excel is a bit of a manual process and involves selecting all the columns you want to sort.  In a pivot table, the interface might make sorting easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is:

- enter your data in 2 columns
- in the first columns write the criteria such as (overall rank, camera rank and so)
- in the next columns write the corresponding value.
- mark the 2 columns
- choose data tab from the ribbon, and then choose filter
- you will see two small arrows in the first two cells in each columns

just press the one in the criteria column and check the box next to the items you would like to see ;)